# Specifically changing one cell within a tableview populated with array elements

Tags: swift, uitableview, indexing, tableview, cell

If I have a tableview that is populated with elements from an array but I want the first cell to be some specific element not within the array if some variable equals whatever, and then have the array populate the rest of the cells after it, how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Why not use two sections? One for the extra value and one for the array of data.

Answer (score 1):

Check `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview

Using an if statement, return a different cell when `row == 0` then return cells reflecting the array afterward.